# Adding a where condition to an ngFor

Tags: angular

I am looping through an array but would like to only show a subset of the elements.

I am using this code to loop through every element of `active`

```
<div *ngFor="let p of (active | keys)">
    {{ p.name }}
</div>
```

Here is some pseudo code to demonstrate what I am looking for:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of (active | keys) where p.age > 18">
    {{ p.name }}
</div>
```

Is there any way to specify conditions so only those with `p.age > 18` will be shown?

I know I could use an `*ngIf` within the loop but I am curious to see whether I can apply my condition within the `*ngFor`

Comment: Why not filter the array in the class, rather than trying to do it in the template? Or, if you do want it in the template, why not write a pipe? You can see in the docs what is supported in the ngFor syntax: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: I think a pipe is a good idea but as I already have one I am unsure how to apply a pipe on a pipe!

Comment: `active | keys | otherPipe`? Note this is also in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#chaining-pipes.

Comment: You'd better maintain a filtered copy in the component. Angular chose not to have such a pipe for good reasons: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: You could add a *ngIf inside your ngFor loop?

Comment: Maybe you can use ngSwitch?

Comment: @JBNizet the page has been changed for the link you shared.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Usually as a good practice you should reduce as much as you can having logic on the view. Having this I would filter the array on the component and then iterate it on the view.

If you want you can keep the original array and then create a getter for the filtered array

```
get filterByAge() {
  return active.filter( x => x.age > 18);
}
```

And then in your loop just do

```
<div *ngFor="let p of filterByAge">
{{ p.name }}
```

Comment: another way is using a ngIf to show or not the p.name < ng-container *ngIf="p.age>18">{{p.name}}< /ng-container >

Answer (score 2):

Completely from the view, you can filter out content as follows

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let p of (active | keys)">
    <div *ngIf="p.age > 18">
        {{ p.name }}
    </div>
</ng-container>
```